# android ExpandableListView add button setonchildclicklistener not working

Tags: android, listview, button

The following code

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:singleLine="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="This is Desc" />
```

The procedure setOnGroupClickListener works

```
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
         @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

However, if you add a button

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/iconShowParamGroup"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"            
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:onClick="showParamGroup" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="This is Desc" />
```

That procedure setOnGroupClickListener does not work. 
And accordingly generate the following shall not be disclosed.
Can you point me to a mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529472/expandablelistview-onchildclicklistener-not-work/42808743

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529472/expandablelistview-onchildclicklistener-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the Button that you add into the item gaining the item focus and onClick event, just set the Button focusable to false. Check this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/iconShowParamGroup"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="showParamGroup" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the ExpandableListView list has not been disclosed. What could interfere?

Comment: This solution does not work with Android 6.0.1. I have a ToggleButton with focusable = false and this button gets all the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the parameter `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your *ExpandableListView*:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/treatments_expandable_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
```

Comment: Since then four years have passed and I have already learned a lot.  But thanks for your answer!