# How to set onClickListener on ExpandibleListAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to display an ExpandableListAdapter in my android activity.
So I have build this code in main_activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.results_activity);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        ResultDAO manager = new ResultDAO(this);

        listAdapter = new ResultExpandableListAdapter(this, lista, listChildData);

    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             "Group Clicked " + lista.get(groupPosition),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                lista.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            lista.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
    });

            // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            lista.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listChildData.get(
                                    "a").get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
    });
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("pippo");
        }
    }
```

Now if I try to run my application, I can see all group but if I try to click on one items, never method is called, then I can't see the child row.

> EDIT
>   This is the ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ResultExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<Result> _listDataHeader; // header titles

    private HashMap<String, List<ResultXResult>> _listDataChild;

    public TextView startDate, endDate,examination;
    public TextView parameter, value,interpretation,description,minMax;

    public ResultExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Result> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<ResultXResult>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ResultXResult result = (ResultXResult) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.results_x_result_list_item, null);
        }

        parameter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parameter);
        value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.valueUm);
        interpretation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.interpretation);
        minMax= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minMax);
        description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        parameter.setText(result.getInfo().getDisplayName());
        value.setText(result.getValue()+" "+result.getValueRanceDescription());
        interpretation.setText(result.getInterpretationCode().getDisplayName());
        minMax.setText(result.getValueRangeMin()+" / "+result.getValueRangeMax());
        description.setText(result.getValueRanceDescription());

        //txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Result result = (Result) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.results_list_row, null);
        }

        startDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
        startDate.setText(result.getDateStart());
        endDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.endDate);
        examination = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.examination);

        startDate.setText(result.getDateStart()!=null ? result.getDateStart() : "");
        endDate.setText(result.getDateEnd()!=null ? result.getDateEnd() : "");
        examination.setText(result.getInfo().getDisplayName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure getChildrenCount() return a value different of 0

Comment: No, and this is strange, because I have insert a breakpoint in some method as getChildId,getChildView, getChildrenCount, and when I starting the application these method are not called

Answer (score 0):

**To extends BaseExpandableListAdapter in your ExpandableAdapter**

```
// that your ResultExpandableListAdapter

private class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childrenData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView != null) {
        text = (TextView)convertView;
        text.setText(childrenData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
    } else {
        text = createView(childrenData.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
    }
    return text;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childrenData.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupData.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupData.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView != null) {
        text = (TextView)convertView;
        text.setText(groupData.get(groupPosition));
    } else {
        text = createView(groupData.get(groupPosition));
    }
    return text;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private TextView createView(String content) {
    AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(  
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 38);  
    TextView text = new TextView(list_tempat.this);  
    text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);  
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);  
    text.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);  
    text.setText(content);
    return text;
  }
}

private void showMessage(String message) {
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

more details [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529472/expandablelistview-onchildclicklistener-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getAdapter`. Change that in the `onCreate` for:

```
expListView.getExpandableListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: the method getExpandableListAdapter does not accept any input parameter.