# Starting new activities from Expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an Expandable listview and I'm trying to start a new activity by clicking on the child row, But it doesn't work with me

Also I want to add child items and parent items both dynamically to be able to change them with several strings from string.xml

```
package com.example.khloud.finaaaaaal_hospital;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Third extends ExpandableListActivity implements
    OnChildClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();
    expandbleLis.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandbleLis.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandbleLis.setClickable(true);

    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    MyExpandableAdapter mNewAdapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(groupItem, childItem);
    mNewAdapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
            this);
    getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
    expandbleLis.setOnChildClickListener(this);
}

public void setGroupData() {

    groupItem.add("htc");
    groupItem.add("sony");
}

ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void setChildGroupData() {

    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("1");

    childItem.add(child);

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("1");
    child.add("2");
    childItem.add(child);


}

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    Intent child0Intent = new Intent(Third.this, Final_list.class);
    startActivity(child0Intent);

    return true;}}
```

Comment: It looks like this may resolve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20792366/6526330

Comment: I have tried the answers in that link and also the same problem exists